# How to add an array to existing array at a specific row?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to add a new array to another array at after row 1,

```
a=np.arange(1,17).reshape(4,4)
b=np.zeros((1,4),dtype=np.uint8)
c=np.concatenate((a,b),0)
```

When i try this it adds it after the last row

```
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16]
 [ 0  0  0  0]]
```

I want to add it after row 1 so it should look like this

```
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 0  0  0  0]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16]]
```

Comment: `c[[0,1,4,2,3],:] ` produces the desired array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c = np.insert(a, 2, b, axis=0)`

Numpy Insert ([documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html))